# Same Entity in Bidirectional OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm trying to find a solution about this problem:
I have a relationship table that map the rules of another entity.

```
    @Entity
public class Relation {
   @Id
   public Long id;
   @OneToOne
   public Address addressHome;
   @OneToOne
   public Address addressWork
}
```

and a class Address

```
@Entity
    public class Address {
       @Id
       public Long id;
    }
```

I would put a bidirectional relation from Address to relation.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: not sure what you are asking for: your problem is about how to tell hibernate about the 2 different addresses in Relation class, or it's about adding relation link into address class?

Comment: my problem is related to add relation link into address class

Comment: Can you add into question a detail on how the 2 database tables are ? Thanks

Comment: I have a @OneToOne on both address field, but I'm not sure u are asking that. I updated the question with these details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is telling Hibernate the relation between `Address` and `Relation`: 
first you need to implement this into Relation:

```
@Entity
public class Relation {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressHome", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Address addressHome;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressWork", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Address addressWork;
}
```

Then you need to edit your Address class like this:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
   @Id
   public Long id;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "addressHome")
   public Relation relationHome;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "addressWork")
   public Relation relationWork;
}
```

If you prefer you can put the annotations on getter instead on variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but assuming this is all that you have in your code, It should work in that way, maybe you are forgetting the @JoinColumn label specifying the name of the database fields. I suggest to put more information about how your data model is related.